# How to conduct a fermata over a rest?

Tags: beginner, orchestra, conducting, rests, fermata

I'm currently learning how to conduct *Berlioz's Symphonie Fantastique - Reveries and Passions*. In the first few bars there are fermatas over a few rests and I know I'm supposed to prolong and hold the rest, but what do with my hand? Am I supposed to treat it as I do with notes that have fermata? Or do something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap up the previous note.  Do nothing for a suitable amount of time (but don't drop your hands. Keep the orchestra's attention).  Give an upbeat into the continuation.